# which one I should use Noun or Gerund? Are both sentences correct?

Tags: grammar, differences, nouns, gerunds

> Run is good for your heart

or

> Running is good for your heart

I cannot understand what the differences between these two sentences are.

Comment: The first sentence is not grammatical.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Beginning a sentence with a verb in the present tense is commonly used as an instruction or command, such as: Run to the store and buy some milk!.  Telling someone to do something.  Imperative case.

A gerund used as the first word is usually forming a noun from a verb, a verbal noun, referring to the concept or activity of "running".  It is like saying,   "the activity of running is good for your heart"

Comment: But  ,,Run is good for your heart" run is noun, I'm interested in how I know when I should write noun (f.e. run, travel, talk) and when gerunds (f.e. running, traveling, talking).  I can not understand the difference between noun and gerund, (run vs running). Thank you

Comment: The word ]"run"  can be either a noun or a verb,   usually when it is used as a noun it would have an article with it such as   "A run is good for your heart"    but normally in English we would say  Running is good for your heart.  used the way you did it is not clear if run is a verb or a noun since you did not use an article such as  A or The  to show that it is a noun in this sentence and not a verb.

Comment: To answer your question more clearly,  Whenever you are using a word that can be either a noun or a verb and you are using it as a noun in an example such as yours,  Use the Gerund to form a verbal-noun.   Travelling is fun,  for example.